# How to push values of an array inside a function to an empty global array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Maybe this is fairly simple and I'm missing something: The problem that I encountered is that I'm pushing the entire array as is into the new one, thus getting an array of arrays. The end result should only contain the values of the array within a function, which should be like this: const testArrayTwo = ["1", "2", "3"];

```js
const testArrayTwo = [];

console.log(testArrayTwo);


function testSomething() {
  const testArray = ["1", "2", "3"];
  console.log(testArray);

  testArrayTwo.push(testArray);
}
```

Comment: You are not calling the function `testSomething`

Comment: Check out the [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).  `testArrayTwo.push(...testArray);`

Comment: Do you want to add all elements of `testArray` into `testArrayTwo`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `push` method of the array adds the parameter as a single element in the end of the array, thus this is adding a new array inside the `testArrrayTwo` array. If you want to add only the values you can use for Each:

```
testArray.forEach((e) => {
  testArrrayTwo.push(e)
}
```

Also, you can use the spread operator and make it even simpler:

`testArrayTwo.push(...testArray)`

Answer (score 0):

You weren't calling the function.

```js
const testArrayTwo = [];

function testSomething() {
  const testArray = ["1", "2", "3"];
  console.log(testArray);
  testArrayTwo.push(testArray);
}

testSomething()
```